# XML schema validation length of a string

Tags: java, python-3.x, xml, unicode

I‘m having trouble to understand, what the length restriction means to strings in XML schema language. I tested two different XMLSchema validator implementations and got inconsistent results. I used the following schema and file for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<test xmlns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema NewXMLSchema.xsd ">
   <id>&#x1f600;xx</id>
</test>
```

and

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" xmlns:tns="http://www.example.org/NewXMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">
    <simpleType name="MyFixedString">
       <restriction base="string">
          <maxLength value="3"></maxLength>
       </restriction>
    </simpleType>
    <complexType name="NewComplexType">
        <sequence>
            <element name="id" type="tns:MyFixedString"></element>
        </sequence>
    </complexType>
    <element name="test" type="tns:NewComplexType"></element>
</schema>
```

The IDE pycharm gives an error in underlining the id element with a read line, that it isn‘t schema compliant. The python code executed with Python 3 says the XML file is schema compliant. 
I wonder if the XML file s schema-compliant or not. I think the point is, how chars (whatever that term exactly means) are counted: The length of a string is the number of unicode codepoints or the number of utf16 surrogates or the number of graphemes.

Is it possible, that the implementation (Python 3, which used AFAIK UFT-32) and Java (UTF-16) leaks into the XMLSchema validation?

Any suggestings?

-- Mik

BTW: The Java 8 builtin schema processor complains my example is not schema compliant, too.

Comment: *"Is it possible, that the implementation (Python 3, which used AFAIK UFT-32) and Java (UTF-16) leaks into the XMLSchema validation?"* --- Yes, but only because the validator implementation is **flawed**. XML specifically define a string as a sequence of characters, and a character as being a Unicode Code Point, specifically excluding surrogate pairs ([2.2 Characters](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets)). Which means a validator that counts `UTF-16` values is flawed.

Comment: However, read the warning note about [`maxLength`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-2/#rf-maxLength): ***Note:** For string and datatypes ·derived· from string, `maxLength` will not always coincide with "string length" as perceived by some users or with the number of storage units in some digital representation. Therefore, care should be taken when specifying a value for `maxLength` and in attempting to infer storage requirements from a given value for `maxLength`.*

Comment: Of course the definition what a char is, is in Unicode a bit ambiguous. m̂ , perceived from a user as one "char"  is built from two codepoints: 0x6d 0x302.

Comment: That is exactly what the `maxLength` warning is cautioning: *"string length" as **perceived***, i.e. `m̂` is displayed as *1 glyph*, is represented as *2 Unicode characters* (`0x6d 0x302`), but may need e.g. *3 bytes* for storage (UTF-8: `0x6D 0xCC 0x82`), so is the length 1, 2, or 3? The *definition* of `maxLength` is clear for string values: Length is 2, i.e. number of Unicode characters, excluding surrogate pairs.

Answer (score 3):

The correct semantics of maxLength is that it applies to the number of Unicode characters (codepoints) and not to the number of octets (or 16-bit code units) in any particular encoding of the string.

Whether all schema validators out there actually conform to this definition, I cannot say. But the definition is clear.

Your sample validates fine using the Saxon schema validator, by the way.

Comment: Well the JDK 8 builtin validator does it wrong. AFAIK pycharm is built in Java and therefore counts UTF-16 surrogates, which is apparently wrong. -- Mik.

Comment: See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8222991